# Spring security custom fields

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, spring-security

1) How can i add a custom field in my login form and use that value to navigate to a different page after login. I need a custom authentication provider for authenticating. Can we use spring mvc to tie all this?

2) How can we get hold of HttpSession in auth provider?

Answer (score 0):

1) I guess, you can choose the default behavior by implementing your own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and passing it to `<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="..."/>`

2) This is actually not in the vein of the separation of concerns paradigm in Spring Security where the authentication provider populates the `Authentication` object and another filter persists/populate the authentication in/from the HTTP session. Nevertheless, you can in general have access to the current HTTP request and, therefore a session, from anywhere inside the request processing chain by adding the filter `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` to your `web.xml`. Use then `((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession()` to reach the session from your authentication provider.